# Uniform grid Rows and Columns

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to make a grid based on a UniformGrid to show the coordinates of each cell, and I want to show the values on the X and Y axes like so:

```
   _A_ _B_ _C_ _D_
1 |___|___|___|___|
2 |___|___|___|___|
3 |___|___|___|___|
4 |___|___|___|___|
```

Anyway, in order to do that I need to know the number of columns and rows in the Uniform grid, and I tried overriding the 3 most basic methods where the arrangement / drawing happens, but the columns and rows in there are 0, even though I have some controls in my grid. What method can I override so my Cartesian grid knows how many columns and rows it has?

C#:

```
public class CartesianGrid : UniformGrid
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        Size size = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);

        int computedColumns = this.Columns; // always 0
        int computedRows = this.Rows; // always 0

        return size;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        Size size = base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);

        int computedColumns = this.Columns; // always 0
        int computedRows = this.Rows; // always 0

        return size;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {`enter code here`
        int computedColumns = this.Columns; // always 0
        int computedRows = this.Rows; // always 0

        base.OnRender(dc);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<local:CartesianGrid>
    <Label Content="Hello" />
    <Label Content="Hello" />
    <Label Content="Hello" />
    <Label Content="Hello" />
    <Label Content="Hello" />
    <Label Content="Hello" />
</local:CartesianGrid>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no property exposed that gives you that information. If you have reflector you can see the calculation they do in the `UpdateComputedValues` method to find the number of rows and columns they use.

In the case where `Rows`, `Columns`, and `FirstColumn` are zero you can use something like this

```
int numVisibleChildren = this.Children.Count((c) => c.Visibility != Visibility.Collapsed);
int numColumns = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(numVisibleChildren));
int numRows = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(numVisibleChildren));
```

I haven't actually run the code though so there are probably some typos.

Comment: Wow your solution is really simple, only I had to change numRows to use Math.Ceiling too. I came up with another solution myself, but I like yours a lot more (posted my solution in the question). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but your solution didn't work, although is much simpler. In our case the number of columns and number of rows are not the same. So I had to use my solution to calculate the real number of columns and rows, without assuming those numbers are the same. Thanks!

Comment: Actually nvm, it was easier from the beginning, in our project the columns and rows are specifically set through a DependencyProperty, your solution should work fine when the Columns and Rows are NOT set, which is what I was aiming for at first. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the complete solution, handles specifying or not specifying the Columns and Rows of the UniformGrid:

```
public class CartesianGrid : UniformGrid
{
    private int _columns;
    private int _rows;
    private int _margin = 20;

    public CartesianGrid()
    {
        // add some margin so the letters and numbers do show up
        this.Margin = new Thickness(_margin, _margin, 0, 0);
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        double xOffset = (this.RenderSize.Width / _columns);
        double yOffset = (this.RenderSize.Height / _rows);

        double xCenterOffset = xOffset / 2;
        double yCenterOffset = yOffset / 2.3;

        for (int i = 0; i < _columns; i++)
        {
            dc.DrawText(
                new FormattedText((i + 1).ToString(),
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface("Arial"),
                20,
                Brushes.Black), new Point((i * xOffset) + xCenterOffset, _margin * -1));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < _rows; i++)
        {
            dc.DrawText(
                new FormattedText(((char)(i + 65)).ToString(),
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface("Arial"),
                20,
                Brushes.Black), new Point(_margin * -1, (i * yOffset) + yCenterOffset));
        }

        base.OnRender(dc);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        if (this.Columns != 0 && this.Rows != 0)
        {
            _rows = this.Rows;
            _columns = this.Columns;

            return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);
        }
        else
        {
            Size arrangedSize = base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);

            double maxChildDesiredWidth = 0.0;

            double maxChildDesiredHeight = 0.0;

            //  Measure each child, keeping track of max desired width & height.  
            for (int i = 0, count = Children.Count; i < count; ++i)
            {
                UIElement child = Children[i];

                Size childDesiredSize = child.DesiredSize;

                if (maxChildDesiredWidth < childDesiredSize.Width)
                {
                    maxChildDesiredWidth = childDesiredSize.Width;
                }
                if (maxChildDesiredHeight < childDesiredSize.Height)
                {
                    maxChildDesiredHeight = childDesiredSize.Height;
                }
            }

            if (maxChildDesiredHeight == 0 || maxChildDesiredWidth == 0)
                return arrangedSize;

            _columns = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(this.DesiredSize.Width / maxChildDesiredWidth));
            _rows = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(this.DesiredSize.Height / maxChildDesiredHeight));

            return arrangedSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, this is what I wanted to achieve:

http://wpfdude.blogspot.com/2010/06/cartesian-grid.html

Thanks!